# Is there any way to convert ppt slides to images and video using office web add-ins?

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins

I am creating a PowerPoint Web Add-in to export all ppt slides as an image and video format, To do this, I also saw the documentation from the URL "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/powerpoint/powerpoint-add-ins". But, I am not able to find a way to do this and it is also not very helpful.
Can anyone please suggest a way to achieve this task?

Comment: https://www.zamzar.com/convert/ppt-to-jpg/